# Writing a Publisher and Subscriber with a Custom Message(Python) Tutorial Not Working

Tags: ros-kinetic, custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to follow the tutorial as detailed in this link: (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CustomMessagePublisherSubscriber%28python%29)

I am using ROS Kinetic on ubuntu 16.04.

I was able to build the Person messages fine without errors and using rosmsg show command. ROS was able to find the message and show the following as output:

```
string name
int32 age
```

I created two different packages to run it. One is called the quadrotor_receive node while the other is called the transmit_thrust node. The transmit_thrust runs the custom_talker.py script while the quadrotor_receive runs the custom_listener.py.

I am having the following errors trying to run the custom_listener.py by itself. Below is my script on the quadrotor_receive node.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from quadrotor_receive.msg import Person 

def callback(data):
    rospy.loginfo("%s is age: %d" % (data.name, data.age))

def listener():

    rospy.init_node('custom_listener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber("custom_chatter", Person , callback)

    # spin() simply keeps python from exiting until this node is stopped
    rospy.spin()

if __name__=='__main__':
    listener()
```

When I tried to run the above code I get the error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/quadrotor_receive/scripts/custom_listener.py",
> line 4, in 
> from quadrotor_receive.msg import Person ImportError: No module named
> quadrotor_receive.msg

I also tried to replace the line:

from quadrotor_receive.msg import Person

with the following:

```
import quadrotor_receive.msg
```

I then get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/quadrotor_receive/scripts/custom_listener.py",
> line 17, in 
> listener()   File "/home/ted/catkin_ws/src/quadrotor_receive/scripts/custom_listener.py",
> line 11, in listener
> rospy.Subscriber("custom_chatter", Person, callback) NameError: global
> name 'Person' is not defined

So what can I do to make the code run? What did I do wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333805/writing-a-publisher-and-subscriber-with-a-custom-message(python)-tutorial-not-working/) by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-09-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [LeoE](https://answers.ros.org/users/38438/leoe/) on 2019-09-24**:
Can you post your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-09-24**:\

> I created two different packages to run it

Just to check have you got three different packages with a single node in each? For a tutorial we would recommend keeping everything in a single package. If the custom message has been defined in a different package you will need an additional dependency in your CMakeLists.txt file to link to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for replies, I solved my problem by following this tutorial:
[Custom Message](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F3zyAV4alCs)
What I did differently is add the  line in the package.xml
Also in CMakelist.txt I was being smart by uncommenting all the lines here instead of just leaving one line uncommented:

```
 catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES transmit_thrust
  CATKIN_DEPENDS message_runtime roscpp rospy std_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)
```

After changing these files I used just catkin_make at the roof directory omitting the install keyword at the end. And things worked.

---

Originally posted by [haloted](https://answers.ros.org/users/46111/haloted/) with karma: 32 on 2019-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1